# How to load a connection pool dynamically in JavaEE

Tags: jakarta-ee, connection-pooling, application-server

I'm building a web app with JavaEE framework. I'm looking for how to load a connection pool to a database dynamically via a configuration file like properties file or xml file or whatever.

I'm looking for this way because my web app needs a pool connection but I dont know in advance which application's server will be used to launch my web app. It's why I need to find a standard way to load a connection pool for all kind of JavaEE server.

I dont know if it's possible or not at all.. but if you may help me, it'll be very nice for my project.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why is that your concern? Just let the webapp owner worry about configuring the server accordingly. Just let your webapp ask for JNDI name of that pool so it can be used.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way is what @BalusC described above. Configuration of the connection pool is an 'ops' concern, not the application's concern. That is because resources like a JDBC connection, while possibly only relevant to one application, can affect the entire application server from a memory and stability stand point. It's more effective to have a known good implementation provided by the application server then put the responsibility on each application to get it right. It also forces the people responsible for the server to be cognizant of these resources. The application should just perform a lookup. That being said, the exact steps are application server dependent so if you want specifics please let us know which app server you are using.

If you are using JavaEE (5+) APIs the standard way to perform this lookup is using `@PersistenceContext` which will inject an entity manager which is configured in a persistence.xml file that is bundled with your application. The mapping between the connection pool, exposed through JNDI and the named persistence context is performed in this file. Some documentation can be found here https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro003.htm

Typically what we do is have a script that uses the app server's management APIs (RESTful or cmd line) to provision this and other properties (like max memory etc). devs can run this script. Another option would be to distribute your configured application server as a docker container. Each dev. would then simply spin this container up and deploy the app to it. There are several advantages to this approach, namely it can pretty much mimic your entire production environment in a consistent fashion.

Answer (score 0):

All JavaEE server implementations (even Tomcat) provide a way of configuring one or more database connection pools, just so that you don't have to worry about it at the application level.

You get access to a database connection by either injecting a `javax.sql.DataSource`:

```
 @Resource
 private DataSource ds;

 void someMethod() {
     try(Connection conn = ds.getConnection()) {
         Statement st = conn.createStatement();
         // etc
     } 
 }
```

or by performing a JNDI lookup:

```
 void someMethod() {
     try(Context context = new InitialContext();
         DataSource ds = (DataSource)context.lookup("some/name/configured/in/the/server");
         Connection conn = ds.getConnection()) {

         Statement st = conn.createStatement();
         // etc
     } 
 }
```

Modern JavaEE implementations provide a way of using standard names for "some/name/configured/in/the/server" as well. If you're on an older platform then you will need to use platform dependent deployment descriptors to map the configured datasource name to the hard wired name used in your application - but that's another topic.

Comment: Thanks for yours answers. In fact, I need this feature because whether for instance we are 50 developpers to work on this project and each of us have a different JavaEE server, I would reproduce the same runtime environment easily whitout letting the server owner makes some changes on server. Is it possible ? JNDI system is intesresting if I can load by a java class for example a pool connection but I'm not sure if it is possible..